# Using pcre in a c program on windows

Tags: c, pcre

I am trying to build an appliction based upon the pcredemo application. When I try and compile the application in Windows I get the following compiler errors.

```
undefined reference to `_imp__pcre_compile'|
undefined reference to `_imp__pcre_exec'|
undefined reference to `_imp__pcre_free'|
```

Am I missing some .dll files or something?

Comment: Isn't that `_imp_*` some C++ name mangling stuff?

Comment: I'm not sure. As far as I am aware am using C libraries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are linker errors. You need to make sure that you are passing the PCRE .lib files to the linker. Another possible problem could be that your compiler/linker is using a different .lib file format from that used to build the PCRE .lib files.

Answer (score 0):

If you are linking PCRE statically, you need to #define PCRE_STATIC before compiling.